# LINQ in a IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I need to get a sum of different columns. Data:

```
<name>Nina</name>
<avd>Soft</avd>
<reg>Mara</reg>
<salg>11</salg>
<oms>13000000</oms>
<hen>10</hen>

<name>Vera</name>
<avd>Soft</avd>
<reg>Mara</reg>
<salg>1</salg>
<oms>1520000</oms>
<hen>0</hen>

<name>Hans</name>
<avd>Hard</avd>
<reg>Mes</reg>
<salg>2</salg>
<oms>6130000</oms>
<hen>0</hen>

<name>Egzona</name>
<avd>Hard</avd>
<reg>Mes</reg>
<salg>6</salg>
<oms>10505000</oms>
<hen>35</hen>
```

For example:
I need to know wish "reg" or "avd" has most Result(salg * 0.8 + hen * 0.2)

I am using .net 4 c#

this is a IEnumerable so I can use Select().

Comment: Are you storing the data as XML and deserializing it to an `IEnumerable` holding an object of some kind?

Comment: I have a class for IEnumerable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order the items and take the first:

```
var maxItem = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Salg * 0.8 + x.Hen * 0.2)
                   .First();
```

Above assumes you have a class with the properties `Salg` and `Hen`. If your items are still XML you will have to use the `Element()` method to access these properties.

Alternatively you can use [`MaxBy()`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) from the MoreLinq project which would be more efficient here:

```
var maxItem = items.MaxBy(x => x.Salg * 0.8 + x.Hen * 0.2);
```

**Edit:**

In light of the update - you need to group your data by name, sum up each group and order by that sum descending, something like this:

```
var bestSalePersons = items.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                           .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(i => i.Salg * 0.8 + i.Hen * 0.2) })
                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Sum)
                           .Take(5);
```

Comment: Well... 
the thing is a need to do some score, like top 5, I use take(5) instead of .First(), but I getting duplicate's.

Comment: Use the first approach then with `Take(5)` instead of `First()`

Comment: what constitutes a duplicate for you? Same name?

Comment: Like this:

1. Mara 44
2. Mara 34
3. San Diego 30
4. San Diego 24
5. New York 10

Comment: updated the answer - this wasn't clear at all from the sample you provided in your question